# Byte limit in text field (solr 4.10)

Tags: solr

When trying to upload a record into SOLR I am getting the following error:

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at least one immense term in field=\"xml\" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[60, 99, 108, 105, 110, 105, 99, 97, 108, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 32, 120, 109, 108, 110, 115, 61, 34, 117, 114, 110, 58, 104]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 51132\n\tat

....

org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:164)\n\t... 49 more\nCaused by: org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash$MaxBytesLengthExceededException: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 51132\n\tat org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.add(BytesRefHash.java:284)\n\tat

The field is defined as:

```
<field name="xml" type="string_ci" multiValued="false"/>
```

and the field string_ci type is:

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="false">      
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround to index large size terms is to use `text_general` type instead of `string`.

```
i.e. In schema.xml you may replace 

<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="false">      

by 

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="false">
```

Note:

- Solr should be restarted after changing schema.xml
- It is suggested to reindex data after changing schema.xml

Comment: How does a name of a fieldType affect it's behavior in any way?